# Не передаются изображения в base64

Tags: php, javascript, post

Формирую массив, отправляю с js в php, а там не принимаются изображения. Все остальное php принимает. В чем проблема и как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function numbersend(e) {
 var n = $('#n-file').val();
 var arr = [];
 for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
  arr.push($("#namenumber"+i).val() ? "Название номер: "+$("#namenumber"+i).val() : "Номер без названия");
  arr.push("Тип номера: "+$("#typenumber"+i).val());
  arr.push("Класс номера: "+$("#classnumber"+i).val());
  if($("#vidnumber"+i).val().length > 0){
   $("#vidnumber"+i+" option:selected").each(function(){
    arr.push("Вид с окна "+this.text);
   });
  }
  if($("#sannumber"+i).val().length > 0){
   $("#sannumber"+i+" option:selected").each(function(){
    arr.push("Санузел "+this.text);
   });
  }
  arr.push("Кухня: "+$("#kitnumber"+i).val());
  if($("#ofsnumber"+i).is(':checked')) {
   arr.push("Для гостей с ОФВ");
  }
  $.each($("[name=mestonumber"+i+"]"), function() {
    arr.push("Спальные места: "+$(this).val());
  });
  if($("#goustnumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Количество гостей: "+$("#goustnumber"+i).val());
  }
  if($("#maynumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Цена за номер в мае: "+$("#maynumber"+i).val());
  }
  if($("#junenumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Цена за номер в июне: "+$("#junenumber"+i).val());
  }
  if($("#julynumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Цена за номер в июле: "+$("#julynumber"+i).val());
  }
  if($("#augnumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Цена за номер в августе: "+$("#augnumber"+i).val());
  }
  if($("#sepnumber"+i).val() > 0) {
   arr.push("Цена за номер в сентябре: "+$("#sepnumber"+i).val());
  }
  var k = $('#addimg'+i).attr('data-count');
  for(var y=1; y<=k; y++) {
   var team = i+''+y;
   console.log('file'+team);
   encodeImageFileAsURL(team);
  }
 }
 $.post("send.php", {'data[]': arr}, function(result){
   console.log(result);
  }
 );
 console.log(arr);
 function encodeImageFileAsURL(i) {
  var filesSelected = document.getElementById('file'+i).files;
  if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
    var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
   var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
   arr.push('<img src="'+srcData+'">');
    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
  }
 }
}


function addMesto(i) {
 $("#addmesto"+i).before('<select name="mestonumber'+i+'"><option value="Односпальная - 90/130 см">Односпальная - 90/130 см</option><option value="Двуспальная - 131/150 см">Двуспальная - 131/150 см</option><option value="Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см">Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см</option><option value="Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см">Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см</option><option value="Двухъярусная - размер варьируется">Двухъярусная - размер варьируется</option><option value="Диван-кровать - размер варьируется">Диван-кровать - размер варьируется</option><option value="Детская кроватка">Детская кроватка</option><option value="Двухъярусная детская кроватка">Двухъярусная детская кроватка</option></select><br>');
}

function addImgInput(i) {
 var count = Number($("#addimg"+i).attr('data-count'));
 count+=1;
 $("#addimg"+i).before("<input type='file' id='file"+i+count+"' value=''><br>").attr('data-count',count);
}

function addForm(i) {
 var n = $('#n-file').val();
 n = +n+1;
 $('#n-file').val(n);
 $('#nav-table').before('<table><tr><td><label for="namenumber'+n+'">Название номер</label></td><td><input type="text" id="namenumber'+n+'"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="typenumber'+n+'">Тип номера</label></td><td><select id="typenumber'+n+'"><option value="Одноместный">Одноместный</option><option value="Двухместный">Двухместный</option><option value="Трехместный">Трехместный</option><option value="Четырехместный">Четырехместный</option><option value="Пятиместный">Пятиместный</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="classnumber'+n+'">Класс номера</label></td><td><select id="classnumber'+n+'"><option value="Стандарт">Стандарт</option><option value="Аппартаменты">Аппартаменты</option><option value="Люкс">Люкс</option><option value="Полулюкс">Полулюкс</option><option value="Бизнес">Бизнес</option><option value="Эконом">Эконом</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="vidnumber'+n+'">Вид с окна</label></td><td><select id="vidnumber'+n+'" multiple><option value="на море">на море</option><option value="на сад">на сад</option><option value="на бассейн">на бассейн</option><option value="на террасу">на террасу</option><option value="на пляж">на пляж</option><option value="на парк">на парк</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="sannumber'+n+'">Санузел</label></td><td><select id="sannumber'+n+'" multiple><option value="с ванной">с ванной</option><option value="с душем">с душем</option><option value="с джакузи">с джакузи</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="kitnumber'+n+'">Кухня</label></td><td><select id="kitnumber'+n+'"><option value="Нет">Нет</option><option value="Студия">Студия</option><option value="Миникухня">Миникухня</option></select></td></tr><tr><td><label for="ofsnumber'+n+'">Для гостей с ОФВ</label></td><td><input id="ofsnumber'+n+'" type="checkbox"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="mestonumber'+n+'">Выберите спальные места</label></td><td><select name="mestonumber'+n+'"><option value="Односпальная - 90/130 см">Односпальная - 90/130 см</option><option value="Двуспальная - 131/150 см">Двуспальная - 131/150 см</option><option value="Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см">Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см</option><option value="Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см">Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см</option><option value="Двухъярусная - размер варьируется">Двухъярусная - размер варьируется</option><option value="Диван-кровать - размер варьируется">Диван-кровать - размер варьируется</option><option value="Детская кроватка">Детская кроватка</option><option value="Двухъярусная детская кроватка">Двухъярусная детская кроватка</option></select><br><input type="button" id="addmesto'+n+'" value="Добавить ещё место" onclick="addMesto('+n+')"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="goustnumber'+n+'">Количество гостей</label></td><td><input type="number" id="goustnumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="maynumber'+n+'">Цена за номер в мае</label></td><td><input type="number" id="maynumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="junenumber'+n+'">Цена за номер в июне</label></td><td><input type="number" id="junenumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="julynumber'+n+'">Цена за номер в июле</label></td><td><input type="number" id="julynumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="augnumber'+n+'">Цена за номер в августе</label></td><td><input type="number" id="augnumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="sepnumber'+n+'">Цена за номер в сентябре</label></td><td><input type="number" id="sepnumber'+n+'" value="0"></td></tr><tr><td><label>Фотографии</label></td><td><input type="file" id="file'+n+'1" value=""><br><input type="button" id="addimg'+n+'" data-count="1" value="Добавить изображение" onclick="addImgInput('+n+')"></td></tr></table>');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}
td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
input[type=text], input[type=number], select {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  color: #353535;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="uploadImages" id="uploadImages" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="namenumber1">Название номер</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="text" id="namenumber1">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="typenumber1">Тип номера</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select id="typenumber1">
    <option value="Одноместный">Одноместный</option>
    <option value="Двухместный">Двухместный</option>
    <option value="Трехместный">Трехместный</option>
    <option value="Четырехместный">Четырехместный</option>
    <option value="Пятиместный">Пятиместный</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="classnumber1">Класс номера</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select id="classnumber1">
    <option value="Стандарт">Стандарт</option>
    <option value="Аппартаменты">Аппартаменты</option>
    <option value="Люкс">Люкс</option>
    <option value="Полулюкс">Полулюкс</option>
    <option value="Бизнес">Бизнес</option>
    <option value="Эконом">Эконом</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="vidnumber1">Вид с окна</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select id="vidnumber1" multiple>
    <option value="на море">на море</option>
    <option value="на сад">на сад</option>
    <option value="на бассейн">на бассейн</option>
    <option value="на террасу">на террасу</option>
    <option value="на пляж">на пляж</option>
    <option value="на парк">на парк</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="sannumber1">Санузел</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select id="sannumber1" multiple>
    <option value="с ванной">с ванной</option>
    <option value="с душем">с душем</option>
    <option value="с джакузи">с джакузи</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="kitnumber1">Кухня</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select id="kitnumber1">
    <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
    <option value="Студия">Студия</option>
    <option value="Миникухня">Миникухня</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="ofsnumber1">Для гостей с ОФВ</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="ofsnumber1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="mestonumber1">Выберите спальные места</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <select name="mestonumber1">
    <option value="Односпальная - 90/130 см">Односпальная - 90/130 см</option>
    <option value="Двуспальная - 131/150 см">Двуспальная - 131/150 см</option>
    <option value="Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см">Широкая (King-size) - 151/180 см</option>
    <option value="Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см">Широкая двуспальная (Super-King-size) - 181/210 см</option>
    <option value="Двухъярусная - размер варьируется">Двухъярусная - размер варьируется</option>
    <option value="Диван-кровать - размер варьируется">Диван-кровать - размер варьируется</option>
    <option value="Детская кроватка">Детская кроватка</option>
    <option value="Двухъярусная детская кроватка">Двухъярусная детская кроватка</option>
   </select><br>
   <input type="button" id="addmesto1" value="Добавить ещё место" onclick="addMesto(1)">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="goustnumber1">Количество гостей</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="goustnumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="maynumber1">Цена за номер в мае</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="maynumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="junenumber1">Цена за номер в июне</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="junenumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="julynumber1">Цена за номер в июле</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="julynumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="augnumber1">Цена за номер в августе</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="augnumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label for="sepnumber1">Цена за номер в сентябре</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="sepnumber1" value="0">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <label>Фотографии</label>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="file" id="file11" value=""><br>
   <input type="button" id="addimg1" value="Добавить изображение" data-count="1" onclick="addImgInput(1)">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table id="nav-table">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" id="n-file">
   <input type="button" id="addform" value="Добавить ещё объект" onclick="addForm(1)">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input onclick="numbersend()" type="button" value="Отправить">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

А принимаю всё это так:

```
<?php
    if($_POST != Array()) {
        print_r($_POST['data']);
    } else {
        echo "Массив пустой";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Без кода вряд ли можно разобраться

Comment: @labris, добавил, но подозреваю что проблема в другом.. может какое то ограничение есть? На POST запрос насколько я знаю его нет.

Comment: Попробовал: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWONQq?editors=1111 - изображение не передается в массиве.

Comment: вы jQuery не подключили, но тоже вижу что здесь не передается. Почему такое может быть? У меня на компьютере передается в массив, но не отправляется

Comment: jQuery там в начале стоит, он подключен. По ходу, что-то во время преобразования картинки не то, поэтому выдает пустое поле. Надо проверить а) добавление, если поле обычное и б) отдельно что выдают функции, связанные с изображением

Comment: По ходу для картинки нету arr.push, вот она и не попадает.

Comment: @labris, вы правы, изображения не добавлялись в массив. Сделал так, чтобы при выборе изображения оно сразу кодировалось в base64, а при отправке формы я уже формирую массив и отправляю. Спасибо вам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще при отправке файла, картинки пост запросом они попадают в глобальный массив $_FILES

http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Но они попадают только при срабатывании submit, а у меня без него